# Limit result per category with Laravel 4.2 MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I've to build a research system for an announcements website. We can search through categories or via the announcement city.

When someone research something **I want to set a limit of results per category (example : 3)** using Eloquent.

I know this isn't easy at all, even in raw SQL, and it's been hours i'm trying to find a way without success. I tried to add a closure in the query but it's very hard for me to understand how to use that properly ...

I understood i needed to make a subquery to do the trick, but it's also tricky to know how to organize all this.

The workbench (followed by the current query which isn't working) :

[image]

Here's the controller with the query :

```
  $announcements = Announcement::select('announcements.*')
                               ->withCitySlug($location)
                               ->withCategory($category_id)
                               ->perCategoryLimit(3)
                               ->get();
```

The model Announcement (the interesting part) :

```
  /**
   * HasManyThrough
   */
  public function categories()
  {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'announcement_categories');

  }

  public function scopeWithCitySlug($query, $city_slug) {

    if (empty($city_slug)) return $query;

    return $query->where('city_slug', 'LIKE', '%'.$city_slug.'%');

  }

  public function scopeWithCategory($query, $category_id) {

    if ($category_id === FALSE) return $query;

    return $query->join('announcement_categories', 'announcement_categories.announcement_id', '=', 'announcements.id')
                 ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'announcement_categories.category_id')                 ->where('categories.id', '=', $category_id);

  }

  public function scopePerCategoryLimit($query, $limit) {

    return $query;

    /*return $query->with(array('categories' => function($q)
    {

        $q->limit(3)->get();

    }));*/


  }
```

Any Eloquent/SQL expert around here ? A little help in the way to solve this would be perfect ;)

PS : If i didn't give enough code to understand the problem, just let me know !

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can select all categories and use an foreach with a limit to get all results or use partition by from sql.